# Define main file to always be run on C-c C-c in emacs elpy

Tags: python, emacs, elpy

When I am working on a file in my application in emacs/elpy, I always have to jump back into my main file buffer and do `C-u C-c C-c` (i.e. ) in order to run and debug it in the python shell. This is rather time consuming, so I was wondering, how can I define a corresponding `C-u C-c C-c` binding but which always runs my defined main file?